# Class return type

Tags: python, class, types, return

I'm trying to build a class that returns a dictionary when you call it. For instance this code:

```
class foobar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Dictionary = {}
        self.DictAddition()

    def DictAddition(self):
        self.Dictionary["Foo"] = "Bar"  

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr([self.Dictionary])
```

When I call the class in my script like so will output class 'foobar.foobar'

```
Object = getattr(foobar, foobar)
Data = Object()
print(type(Data))
```

All tho I can print Data and it will print as expected a Dictionary, but I can't loop through the dictionary as it gives a TypeError, object is not iterable. Is there a way I can really return a type Dictionary from a class?

with kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want an object that behaves just like a dictionary, except for some special behavior that occurs during object creation? Sounds like an excellent time to use inheritance.

```
class foobar(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(foobar, self).__init__()
        self["Foo"] = "Bar"  

data = foobar()
print data
for item in data:
    print "Item:", item
```

Result:

```
{'Foo': 'Bar'}
Item: Foo
```

Now, printing and iteration and everything else a dict can do, can also be done with your `foobar` class.

Comment: Or just `super(foobar, self).__init__(Foo="Bar")`

Answer (score 2):

I must say I don't really understand what you are trying to do here: just making `repr` print a dictionary doesn't make your class one. But if you want to enable iteration for a class, you will need to override the `__iter__` method.